# WebKit's Audits tool - runs forever

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit

I'm trying to use WebKit's [audits panel](http://www.webkit.org/blog/1091/more-web-inspector-updates/#audits_panel) to remove some unused CSS in a fairly complicated webapp I'm working on.  It loads forever, and it's not a bug in WebKit because it works well on other sites.  All resources have finished loading - there are no pending requests that I can see, and I think JavaScript should be idling too...

This happens both in Chrome and Safari (latest), OS X 10.7.

Any ideas?

[image: Loading (33 of 33) forever]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since recently, canary Chrome allows you to stop running audits, but the best option possible would be coming up with a publicly available test case URL that can be accessed by developers, and filing a respective bug using http://new.crbug.com (mention "DevTools" in the summary line and set the "Feature-DevTools" label if possible.)

Comment: Was about to answer this question myself - I saw the "stop running audits" patch when I did some investigating.  Then I got some sense and tried the latest nightly and found out that the bug has been fixed.  So anyone having this issue can use a later version of WebKit for debugging.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find that Webkit's audit runs forever when it has no errors to find. It's a bug and it's probably reported. What I usually do is just restart the browser and do another audit. That usually works. In the meantime I'm sure a fix will be out

Comment: Tried restarting the browser multiple times.  Also I know there should be at least one error because one thing it checks is unused CSS classes, of which there are plenty on this page.